# Do cached values survive servlet restarts?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When a Java servlet stops and later a new one spawns in Google Appengine environment, will cached (MemCache) values survive and will be still in cache? Or a new servlet instance always come with an empty cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memcache is a service that is decoupled from the VM instance, it should "survive" a restart, but as always when it comes to memcache your code must never assume that the value is going to be available at any point.

Comment: In addition to this, it is also worth noting the Memcache is shared across instances.